# AngularJS communicating event/change from service to controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service, angularjs-controller

I'm trying to communicate between two controllers. I'm aware that this can be done by raising an event and then using $rootScope.$broadcast, but is not advisable for large-scale applications. I have seen a lot of blog posts which recommend using a service to communicate, but have not be able to succeed to implement. My actual code is more complicated, but here is the gist:

HTML:

```
<body ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
        <span>Source: {{count}}</span>
        <button ng-click="updateCount()">Increase Count</button>
    </div>
    <div ng-controller="ListCtrl">
        Destination: {{updatedCount}}
    </div>
</body>
```

JS:

```
(function () {

    var app = angular.module("app", []);

    app.factory("ShareDataSvc", function ($log) {

        var currentCount = 0;

        var set = function (val) {
            $log.info('Setting service value to: ' + currentCount);
            currentCount = val;
        }

        var get = function () {
            return currentCount;
        }

        return {
            set: set,
            get: get
        }
    });

    app.controller("MainCtrl", ['$scope', 'ShareDataSvc', function ($scope, ShareDataSvc) {
        $scope.count = ShareDataSvc.get();
        $scope.updateCount = function () {
            $scope.count = $scope.count + 1;
            ShareDataSvc.set($scope.count);
        }
    }]);

    app.controller("ListCtrl", ["$scope", "ShareDataSvc", function ($scope, ShareDataSvc) {
        $scope.updatedCount = ShareDataSvc.get();

        // trigger alert if count updated
        $scope.triggerAlert = function () {
            alert('Count updated!');
        }
    }]);
}());
```

I'm trying to understand why the count in the destination is not updated by Angular even though it is data-bound. It is my understanding that when the count is updated in the SharedDataSvc, the updatedCount property will be recalculated.
What am I doing wrong here? The end result is to trigger the alert on every count update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You run into the old copy by value problem. When you do

```
$scope.updatedCount = ShareDataSvc.get();
```

The updated count property is being set to the value that is returned from your get function, and therefore doesn't see future changes to the value being tracked in your service.   You have two options to get around this. One is to add a watch to each of your controllers to monitor the value in the service.  Not ideal.  The second is to have object property in your service track the value and data bind that object to your scope. Something like (note I only show the interesting parts):

```
app.factory("ShareDataSvc", function ($log) {

    var set = function (val) {
        $log.info('Setting service value to: ' + currentCount);
        this.data.count = val;
    }

    return {
        data: {count: 0}
        set: set
    }
});

app.controller("MainCtrl", ['$scope', 'ShareDataSvc', function ($scope, ShareDataSvc) {
    $scope.data = ShareDataSvc.data;
    $scope.updateCount = function () {
        ShareDataSve.data.count++; // and increment function in the service would be better
    }
}]);

app.controller("ListCtrl", ["$scope", "ShareDataSvc", function ($scope, ShareDataSvc) {
    $scope.data = ShareDataSvc.data;

}]);
```

Then in your HTML

```
<body ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
        <span>Source: {{data.count}}</span>
        <button ng-click="updateCount()">Increase Count</button>
    </div>
    <div ng-controller="ListCtrl">
        Destination: {{data.count}}
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Ah.. I see the problem. Binding to the actual value updates the count in the destination. But I'm still not sure how to trigger the alert. Is $watch the only option?

Comment: It depends on your use case.  If you need to know when it changes in your controllers then you'll need to either have a watch, or emit an event on the rootScope from the service that can be listened for in your controller (more performant then the watch).

Comment: Did you need an example or was the description enough to get you going?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. But I decided to use an event aggregator as shown in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XqDxG/452/).